# Regex Pattern Matching at Beginning of String with BeautifulSoup

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm currently looking for a way to perform pattern matching via regex at the beginning of an HTML class name. The pattern I'm trying to match is:

```
"col-xs-.*"
```

Two examples of classes in the HTML page are:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
<div class="mod-tiles__sizer col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
```

The goal is to only match the above class name, as it actually starts with "col-xs-.*", which is what I am after. Using my current regex matching I can't seem to single these class names out. Currently I'm trying to match using the following regex pattern:

```
regex = re.compile('^col-xs-.*$')
soup.find_all("div", class_ = regex)
```

Unfortunately this pattern also prints out the second class name (where "col-xs-.*" appears in the middle and not just at the start). Hopefully someone has a solution to this issue.

Comment: The `.*` matches till the end of the string. Try `\bcol-xs-\d+\b`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Your solution unfortunately does not seem to work. And does it matter that the .* matches till the end of string? All I need is for the pattern to appear at the beginning of the string, the rest that happens after isn't really that important I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) css selector with starts with ^ operator to specify the prefix string to find in the class attribute.

```
soup.select('[class^="col-xs-"]')
```

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
<div class="mod-tiles__sizer col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
classes = [' '.join(item['class']) for item in soup.select('[class^="col-xs-"]')]
print(classes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this expression might likely extract those desired classes:

```
import re

regex = r"[\"']\s*(\bcol-xs-[0-9]+\b[^\"']+?)\s*[\"']"

test_str = """

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12"><div class="  col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12  ">
<div class="mod-tiles__sizer col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
<div class="mod-tiles__sizer col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">

"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE))
```

#### Output

```
['col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12', 'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12', 'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12']
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5HmXR4/1), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/5HmXR4/1debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find them without beautiful supe, this is the way to do it.
All div tags with a class attribute where `col-xs-` is at the beginning of the value:

Includes whitespace trimming.

```
r"(?i)<div(?=(?:[^>\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')*?(?<=\s)class\s*=\s*(?:(['\"])\s*(col-xs-(?:(?!\1)[\S\s])*?)\s*\1))\s+(?:\"\S\s]*?\"|'\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>"
```

https://regex101.com/r/rsXqI9/1

Formatted:
Class value is in group 2.

```
 (?i)
 < div 
 (?=
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      (?<= \s )
      class \s* = \s* 
      (?:
           ( ['"] )                      # (1)
           \s* 
           (                             # (2 start)
                col-xs-

                (?:
                     (?! \1 )
                     [\S\s] 
                )*?
           )                             # (2 end)
           \s* 
           \1 
      )
 )
 \s+ 
 (?: " \S\s ]*? " | ' \S\s ]*? ' | [^>]*? )+
 >
```